# ¿Como puedo actualizar la información en una capa de QGIS desde PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, funcion, actualizacion

un placer saludarlos!!

Estoy tratando de actualizar una capa en Qgis que se encuentra alojada en una base de datos de PostgreSQL. La idea es que tengo una tabla **a** que es la que quiero actualizar a partir de una tabla **b** que tiene toda la información necesaria. La actualización se ejecutaría en dos posibles escenarios. El primero es crea una nueva geometría (polígono) donde se genera un contador automático en el id y manualmente se le asigna un id_predial. El segundo escenario es que por algún motivo se deba cambiar solo el id_predial a una geometría existente de manera manual. Tengo un leve conocimiento en bases de datos y se que se utiliza un campo en común  para realizar la actualización. La idea es usar una función y un trigguer. Les comparto el código a continuación:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_actualizar_pi()
 RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
 BEGIN                                                                                      ` 
 ---Se activa para inserciones y actualizaciones                                       
 UPDATE pi
 SET 
    "numCuenta" = f."numCuenta",
    "abrDistri" = f."abrDistri",
    "abrBarrio" = f."abrBarrio",
    frente1 = f.frente1,
    frente2 = f.frente2,
    frente3 = f.frente3,
    frente4 = f.frente4,
    "frenteTot" = f."frenteTot",
    "planoCat" = f."planoCat",
    "areaRegis" = f."areaRegis",
    "areaCatas" = f."areaCatas",
    "numFinca" = f."numFinca",
    "codDuplic" = f."codDuplic",
    "indFilial" = f."indFilial",
    "codZonHo" = f."codZonHo",
    "porPosesi" = f."porPosesi",
    "tipDerech" = f."tipDerech",
    latitud = f.latitud,
    longitud = f.longitud,
    "coordenaX" = f."coordenaX",
    "coordenaY" = f."coordenaY",
    "indPalma" = f."indPalma",
    "areaPalma" = f."areaPalma",
    "ideCatast" = f."ideCatast",
    "nomComple" = f."nomComple",
    telefono1 = f.telefono1,
    cedula = f.cedula,
    direccion = f.direccion
FROM info_finca f
WHERE f."ideCatast" = NEW.id_predial AND pi.id = NEW.id;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER trg_actualizar_pi
AFTER UPDATE ON pi
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION fn_actualizar_pi();
```

Agradezco toda ayuda.

Comment: Hola. ¿Y cuál es el problema o error?

Comment: Buenas, el problema es precisamente eso que no me actualiza la información. Se supone que la función debería de tomar los valores de la tabla b del campo "ideCatast" y vincularlo con el campo id_predial de la tabla a de manera automática. en algunos casos me da un problema de recursividad.